# getting sin curve values using python

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I am looking to create a sin curve using python. I want a code to generate the values in the form of a sine curve. Such that if i plot those values i should get this curve. Can someone help me with this ? I should be able to differ the number of values it takes to reach the peak (basically varying the frequency). Thank you

Comment: Just run a for loop and call `math.sin()`. Try writing some code and post it here if you run into trouble.

Comment: @David: He also needs to draw the graphical plot.

Comment: Have you tried *anything* yourself?

Comment: I dont need a graphical plot. I just need the numbers

Comment: Then as David says, run a `for` loop, and include a frequency parameter in math.sin(f*x), or put the frequency in the `for` increment.  It must have taken longer to post this question than it would have to write the two lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you got Matplotlib and NumPy installed?

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
>>> y = np.sin(x)
>>> plt.plot(x, y)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x25d1ed0>]
>>> plt.show()
```

Skip the last few steps if you don't need the plot.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot arbitrary formulas with [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/):

```
import pylab
x = pylab.arange(0,10,0.01)
y = pylab.sin(x)
pylab.plot(x,y)
pylab.show()
```

This will be open an interactive window from where you can save the image. Alternatively, call [`savefig`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig) to store the image in a file. For reference, without any more styling, the result will look like:

[image: Example plot]